# googlesearch package in colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, pypi

I can do following in google colab:

```
import googlesearch as g
urls = list(g.search(search_string, stop=results_count, lang='en'))
```

But I am guessing which package is this `googlesearch`?

I checked [this](https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/) package, but it does not have `stop` parameter in its `search()` method, so I am guessing it is different from whats installed in the colab. (The same parameter is called `num_results` in this API as shown in hello world example in its pypi page linked above.)

How do I know which googlesearch package is installed in colab, perhaps to use it locally on my laptop?

PS: You can check the API in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sIcfBUN9MbCFZXZBKUZkzkj_VNPGruyC?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's installed with `google` package from this link:

https://pypi.org/project/google/

https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch

Comment: This package does not come up when googled "google search pypi" too despite its one of most starred!! Also pypi does not reflect its stars and recent stats. But most importantly, how do you know for sure it is the package installed in colab VM? Is there any command which we can run in colab to know that?

Comment: This package is imported from the location `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/googlesearch/`. You can search for it in the `Files` menu on the left. Python packages are imported from `PATH` location. You can check those in Colab by running `print(sys.path)`.